# Where are per-file editor type overrides stored

Tags: eclipse, metadata, eclipse-metadata

In Eclipse, you have a set of default editors set up in `Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations`. When you open a file, if you select "Open With" and choose an editor other than the default for that file type, Eclipse remembers which editor you chose for that file, and uses it again when you re-open that file later.

Where are these per-file overrides for which editor to use stored?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse saves this information in the following file under the workspace:

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workbench.xml
```

In that file, there are `editor` tags for the files being used in the workbench which associate them to the corresponding editors.

Comment: Located the folder you indicated, but it does not contain `workbench.xml`. It only contains `dialog_settings.xml` which does not have any `editor` tags. I'm currently using Kepler, build 20130919-0819

Comment: @MartinCarney How about `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi`? Seems the file in the answer is for 3.x versions.

Comment: Found that file as well. It only has one reference to a file I've opened in a non-default editor, and there should be several files referenced.

Answer (score 0):

If Open With has been used to select a specific editor this is stored using

```java
IFile file = ... the file

file.setPersistentProperty(IDE.EDITOR_KEY, "editor id");
```

where `IDE` is `org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE`.

you can use `file.getPersistentProperty(IDE.EDITOR_KEY)` to get this value.

Comment: What is this in context of? Sounds like Eclipse plugin development, maybe?

Comment: Yes, this is what you do in plugin development. The file persistent properties are stored in the workspace metadata in a format that is not easily accessible except using this API.